# Catch Click event on a control with MessageFilter

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have tried to catch the click events on my app controls with `IMessageFilter` and `PreFilterMessage`. But I only achieve to catch the mouse click, not the event from the control.

In my application, I need the message from the control to log the control's name and type.

I've used the following code to catch mouse events with `if (m.Msg >= 513 && m.Msg <= 515)`:

```
public class TestMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        // Filter click events with a message number ?
        if (m.Msg == ?)
        {
            // Log stuff
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to catch Click events with IMessageFilter or another filter?

Comment: You could make a custom event and send your data trough it.

Comment: The application is to big and it will take to much time to modify all of the controls inside the app. We used "standard" events, so I think I'm just missing something on the filter (maybe the correct message number or name).

Comment: You cannot get a managed event by filtering the message pump. Your message filter can only give you a click event: after that you need to check current cursor coordinates and find the clicked control yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (in a word). MessageFilter is what it says on the tin, it filters the system windows messages. It has nothing to do really with managed code, it is listening for windows messages and filtering them.

Once caught however, you can react to the message and do whatever you like - i.e. call the managed code you want, track key or mouse position etc. In your case, you would need to locate the mouse position and check if the click was over a control, then call the click event manually.

Comment: From MSDN: "Use PreFilterMessage to filter out a message before it is dispatched to a control or form."